# How do you stay green in Teams when in meetings in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

I think Teams and Outlook has the following logic: When I am in a meeting set up using Outlook, then my status in Teams goes Red.

Is there a way to configure Teams to ignore this and keep me Green?

Answer (score 1):

On the calendar where the meeting is, try marking yourself as available. You won't go red, but you'll still be marked as away after 15 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, but for fix per meeting can also be done by hovering over Teams in the bottom bar and set it to green. I am more interested in a permanent setup if it exists.

Comment: I didn't find one in MS docs, but I'm interested if you find out. Cheers.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such way to permanent set it.